# replacement for AttributeKey

Tags: netty

Attributekeys are depreciated and cause problems with my code.  I looked on the netty wiki and it said I should "Use valueOf(String) instead."  umm, I don't see how finding the value of a string has anything to do with attribute keys.  Anyone have some explanations on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They changed the `AttributeKey`s at some point. They are still there though:

The old way of creating the keys:

```
final static AttributeKey<Long> CHECKSUMKEY = new AttributeKey("calcchecksum");
```

was replaced with this:

```
final static AttributeKey<Long> CHECKSUMKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("calcchecksum");
final static AttributeKey<CustomClass> COMMANDKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("command");
final static AttributeKey<Long> FILEHANDLEKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("filehandle");
final static AttributeKey<File> PATHKEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("destpath");
```

So only the constructor of `AttributeKey` is deprecated. You can the use them like this for example:

```
ctx.channel().attr(Server.PATHKEY).set(file);
File file = ctx.channel().attr(Server.PATHKEY).get();
ctx.channel().attr(Server.PATHKEY).remove();
```

Comment: Nice answer. Could you please also add that what's been deprecated is just the constructor of `AttributeKey`?

Comment: @trustin: done. I noticed in the source code that the new way of constructing the keys just uses the constructor again. What's the reason behind that?